# generalizing the Python porting script

Tags: python

I want to port the data from a text file which is located in a remote server to another remote server. But in this I have to manually set the file name (filepath = filePath='''/Users/linu/Downloads/log''') with this statement and if the file name is different it won't work. So is there anyway of generalizing this script without specifying the file name?

I have tried by using (filepath = filePath='''/Users/linu/Downloads/*.txt''') like this but getting the below error,

```
Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/linu/Downloads/*.txt'
Error adding  information.
```

is this the correct way? Or how can i achieve this/ And is there any other things to generalise on this?

**Note:** I'm using a Mac system and the property of the file is showing as "TextEdit document", cannot find the type of the file(Sorry if this is a fluke, I'm new to Mac environment).

```
import psycopg2
import time

start_time = time.perf_counter()
try:
  conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database="postgres", user="postgres",
                         password="postgres", port="5432")
  print('DB connected')

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        # Confirm unsuccessful connection and stop program execution.
        print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
        print("Database connection unsuccessful.")
        quit()        
try:

    filepath = filePath='''/Users/linu/Downloads/log''' 

    table='staging.stock_dump'

    SQL="""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS """+  table + """;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS """+ table + """
      (created_date TEXT, product_sku TEXT, previous_stock TEXT, current_stock TEXT );"""

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(SQL)
    conn.commit()
    with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
     for line in file:
        if 'Stock:' in line:
            fields=line.split(" ")
            date_part1=fields[0]
            date_part2=fields[1][:-1]
            sku=fields[3]
            prev_stock=fields[5]
            current_stock=fields[7]
            if prev_stock.strip()==current_stock.strip():
                continue
            else:
               #print("insert into " + table+"(created_date, product_sku, previous_stock , current_stock)" + " select CAST('" + date_part1+ " "+ date_part2 + "' AS TEXT)" +", CAST('"+sku+"' AS TEXT),CAST('" + prev_stock +"' AS TEXT),CAST('" +current_stock  + "' AS TEXT) ;")
               cursor.execute("insert into " + table+"(created_date, product_sku, previous_stock , current_stock)" + " select CAST('" + date_part1+ " "+ date_part2 + "' AS TEXT)" +", CAST('"+sku+"' AS TEXT),CAST('" + prev_stock +"' AS TEXT),CAST('" +current_stock  + "' AS TEXT);")

    conn.commit()       
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print("Data loaded to DWH from text file")
    print("Data porting took %s seconds to finish---" % (time.perf_counter() - start_time))

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
        print("Error adding  information.")
        quit()
```

Comment: How about using os.system to run shell command with scp like os.system('scp')? Is that what you want?

Comment: maybe you need to run `python script.py filename` and then you will have this filename in `sys.argv[1]` and you could do `open(sys.argv[1])`. If you use module `argparse` then you can run as `script.py --name filename --output othername`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `os.listdir()` function along with the `os.path.splitext()` in order to tell which files in your directory are textfiles. At that point, you can either choose which file to transfer based on whatever criteria you want, or transfer *all* of them in a `for` loop:

```
possible_files = [f for f in os.listdir('/Users/linu/Downloads') if os.path.splitext(f) == ".txt"]
# possible_files now contains paths of all .txt files in /users/linu/downloads
# you could search through that list somehow to find the one you wanted, or just
#   take possible_files[0] if you wanted (the first .txt file in the directory),
#   or do your code for all of them, as I've demonstrated below
for possible_file in possible_files:
    filePath = os.path.join('/Users/linu/Downloads', possible_file)
    # and now the rest of the code you already wrote
    table = 'staging.stock_dump'
    ...
    conn.close()
```

It occurs to me further that, given your situation, your file might not actually be a `.txt` file - it might just be an ordinary file with no file extension. In which case you might want to use the condition `if os.path.splitext(f) == ''` instead.

Comment: have tried with with both extensions but the result is same, Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL name 'filePath' is not defined
Error adding  information.

Comment: Made   these changes and commented the filepath variable which was previously there,   possible_files = [f for f in os.listdir('/Users/linu/Downloads') if os.path.splitext(f) == ".txt"]
    for possible_file in possible_files:
      filePath = os.path.join('/Users/linu/Downloads/', possible_file)

Comment: You're going to have to debug your code - use some `print` statements in there to see what's going wrong, and why the program things `filePath` is not defined once you get to the next part. Maybe you have the wrong indentation?

Comment: Fixed that error, But the code is not returning the file name,as you said i have printed the file name and it doesn't have an extension  possible_files = [f for f in os.listdir('/Users/linu/Downloads/') if os.path.splitext(f) == ''] and when i print the possible_files it is empty

Comment: Try it without the conditional and see what `possible_files` looks like - then you can determine what you'll need to put in the `if` statement accordingly.